# Proper way of traversing a beautifulsoup4 object

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have some sloppy HTML like this...

```
<span>STATS</span>
<table> ... </table>
<span>Page 1 of 5</span>
```

And some Beautiful Soup code trying to do this..

```
table = soup.find('span', text='STATS').nextSibling('table')[0]
pagespan = table.nextSibling('span')
```

Which throws the exception `TypeError: 'NavigableString' object is not callable`

What's the best way of doing this? No elements have DOM IDs or CSS classes or anything useful or uniquely identifying. There are a whole bunch of tested `table` elements within that `table` but I don't want them. Just stuff at the same DOM level.

Thanks.

Comment: Just remove the `[0]` in first line of code.

Comment: This does not work. Exception: `AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'nextSibling'` --- I think I need to access the first element, since it's the first table found. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The following code is working perfectly fine for me -

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "<span>STATS</span><table> ... </table><span>Page 1 of 5</span>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

table = soup.find('span', text='STATS').find_next_sibling('table')
pagespan = table.find_next_sibling('span')
print pagespan.text
```